# Xcode will open tiny window but not IDE?

Tags: xcode

Sometimes I quit Xcode with only a tiny window I was editing something else in. Now whenever I open my project again it will open the window but not the IDE. Is there any way to physically open the IDE so I can work on my project again?

Comment: If you can provide a screenshot, it would be way easier to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode will usually do this if this style of window is the last to be closed. If this is the case the your window looks like this:

[image]

Then it can be fixed simply by doing the following:

[image]

And finally select what side bars you want to be visible:

[image]